# AngularJS: Using directives as templating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a directive to provide a basic template for many of the pages in my Angular app. It looks like this:

```
angular.module('app.basicLayout', [])
    .directive('basicLayout', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/assets/views/templates/basicLayout.html'
        }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<basic-layout>
    <h1>My layout goes here</h1>
</basic-layout>
```

On some of these pages I would like to add a sidebar and still be able to use the layout from my `<basic-layout>` directive. Is it possible to make something like the following?

```
<basic-layout>
    <h1>My content goes here</h1>

    <the-sidebar>
        <h2>Sidebar content here</h2>
    </the-sidebar>
</basic-layout>
```

**Update**

My template file of the directive currently look like this:

```
<div class="container basic-layout">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div ng-transclude></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If `<the-sidebar>` is set, I would like to change the template file to something like this:

```
<div class="container basic-layout">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!-- The content here -->
            <div ng-transclude></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- The sidebar here -->
            <div ng-transclude></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the exact case for transclusion. You can parametrize your directive layout with some variable layout (sidebar in this case). To do this your have to set the `transclude` property in the directive config object to `true` and also specify where in your directive's layout the changing content should be injected by using the `ng-transclude` directive. Like this:

```
return {
    ...
    transluce: true,
    ...
}
```

and now in the directive template:

```
//other layout here
   <div ng-transclude></div>
```

This way all the content you put inside the `<basic-layout>` directive will be transfered into the element on which you use ng-transclude.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @getOffMyLawn. My template file is consisting of a few Bootstrapped divs and I use the `<div ng-transclude>` inside of that. However, I would like that all the contents in `<the-sidebar>` would be transcluded to a different part of the template file. I updated my question with the template file.

Comment: So basically, you want to transclude the sidebar element to a certain position in your directive template, and the rest to another position? I don't think it's a good idea since it will boil down to a messy DOM manipulation. If  the sidebar has always the same template, you can just put it into the directive template and conditionally show and hide it using `ng-if` directive and an attribute to signalize if the sidebar should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to manually transclude using the `transclude` function passed as a 5th parameter to the `link` function. To make it easier, I would change the template to have placeholders:

```
<div>
  <content-placeholder></content-placeholder>
  <div>
    <sidebar-placeholder></sidebar-placeholder>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, place each content where it belongs:

```
transclude: true,
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
  transclude(function(clone){
     var sidebar = clone.find("the-sidebar").remove();
     element.find("content-placeholder").replaceWith(clone);
     element.find("sidebar-placeholder").replaceWith(sidebar);
  });
}
```

This should work for you, but it's not clear to me why you want to build a directive for a general layout.

If you have many pages in the Web app (in a classical non-SPA sense), then it's probably better to create the scaffolding in a "master page" on the server.

Otherwise, if you mean that you have many "views" of the same app, the I suggest looking into ui-router - specifically into a section of [Nested States and Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views).